# How to set min height for all grid rows?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

I would like to set a min height for all the rows in a grid. This is the xaml.

```
<Grid client:PopulateGrid.DataContext="{Binding Tabular}">
</Grid>
```

The grid is populated by some clever helper code (the PopulateGrid class).

Is it possible to set a min height for all the rows in the xaml?

Answer (score 5):

Declare **`default Style for RowDefinition` under Grid resources** so that it gets applied to all rows inside your Grid and set MinHeight in it.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
```